# On the Blockchain or in the Blockchain

Tags: prepositions

I am not native Engish I have a hard time to distinguish between on and in cases like "the cloud" or "the Blockchain"

For instance: that software is in the Blockchain or on the Blockchain?

Why?

Thank you!